# Email is shown in profile despite (hopefully) already hidden only on SU

Tags: bug, user-profiles, email

I have tried to remove my publicly visible email address several times from the SuperUser section. I have removed it and clicked Save, and Save for all StackOverflow sites.

Only the Super User website shows it under my profile, the other sites show it as empty.

I assume it's not visible based upon an answer I got at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145863/possible-bug-in-user-profile-on-superuser-only#comment417231_145863 but they suggested I also informed you in case you want to action it.

Comment: It's not visible to others from what I can tell.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'll leave it up to 'the powers who are' if they want to make a change or not, I don't need to be involved per se. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is what I see from my point of view, if it helps.

Comment: Well that is not only helpful but definitive too. Thank you.